# Detach Event Handler From Dynamic Object

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection

I am trying to detach an `event handler` using a `dynamic` object. I haven't use `dynamic` much, and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here. The exception I'm receiving is:

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException
>
> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'CollectionChanged'

```
[Fact]
public void Test()
{
    var foo = new Foo();
    foo.Bars = new ObservableCollection<Bar>();
    foo.ClearDelegates();
}
```

```
Dictionary<string, object> _values;
Dictionary<string, NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler> _collectionChangedDelegates;

public void ClearDelegates()
{
    foreach (var kvp in _values)
    {
        var currentValue = _values[kvp.Key];
        if (currentValue == null)
            continue;

        var type = currentValue.GetType();

        if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ObservableCollection<>))
        {
            dynamic observableCollection = currentValue;
            observableCollection.CollectionChanged -= _collectionChangedDelegates[kvp.Key];
        }
    }
}
```

```
class Foo : DomainObject
{
    public ObservableCollection<Bar> Bars
    {
        get { return GetValue<ObservableCollection<Bar>>(nameof(Bars)); }
        set { SetValue(nameof(Bars), value); }
    }
}
```

```
class DomainObject
{
    Dictionary<string, object> _values = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    Dictionary<string, NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler> _collectionChangedDelegates =
        new Dictionary<string, NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler>();


    public void ClearDelegates()
    {
        foreach (var kvp in _values)
        {
            var currentValue = _values[kvp.Key];
            if (currentValue == null)
                continue;

            var type = currentValue.GetType();

            if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ObservableCollection<>))
            {
                dynamic observableCollection = currentValue;
                observableCollection.CollectionChanged -= _collectionChangedDelegates[kvp.Key];
            }
        }

        _collectionChangedDelegates.Clear();
    }


    protected T GetValue<T>(string propertyName)
    {
        return (T)_values[propertyName];
    }

    protected void SetValue<T>(string propertyName, ObservableCollection<T> value)
    { 
        if (value != null)
            HookupCollectionDelegates(propertyName, value);
        
        Set(propertyName, value);
    }

    protected void SetValue<T>(string propertyName, T value)
    {
        Set(propertyName, value);
    }


    void Set<T>(string propertyName, T value)
    {
        _values[propertyName] = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }

    void HookupCollectionDelegates<T>(string propertyName, ObservableCollection<T> collection)
    {
        var collectionChangedDelegate = delegate(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // do work
        };
        collection.CollectionChanged += collectionChangedDelegate;

        if (_collectionChangedDelegates.ContainsKey(propertyName))
            _collectionChangedDelegates[propertyName] = collectionChangedDelegate;
        else
            _collectionChangedDelegates.Add(propertyName, collectionChangedDelegate);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine. [dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EiJjfr). Can you show your usage that throws the exception?

Comment: @Alex That was a literal copy paste. I made the method public, and created a contrived test, edited the main post. Same results. The setter of `Bars` simply inserts into the values dictionary. But I see the fiddle does execute as expected...

Answer (score 3):

I like new features too, but we shouldn't forget the old ones. Your dictionaries look like a relation. I guess it's `Join` time, so help us `LINQ`.

```
Dictionary<string, object> _values;
Dictionary<string, NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler> _collectionChangedDelegates;

void ClearDelegates()
{
    foreach (var i in
        _values.Join(_collectionChangedDelegates,
                     outer => outer.Key,
                     inner => inner.Key,
                     (outer, inner) =>
                     new
                     {
                         Target = (INotifyCollectionChanged)outer.Value,
                         EventHandler = inner.Value
                     })) // expected, you manage your dictionaries carefully
        i.Target.CollectionChanged -= i.EventHandler;

    _collectionChangedDelegates.Clear();
}
```

Comment: Good eye! It's definitely a reference integrity constraint.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid `run-time` `dynamic`-bound issues just stay **strongly typed**. Mind, `CollectionChanged` event is defined in `INotifyCollectionChanged`, not in particular `ObservableCollection<T>`, so you actually **don't** need `dynamic`. This code helps **to avoid issues** at `compile-time`.

```
Dictionary<string, object> _values;
Dictionary<string, NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler> _collectionChangedDelegates;

void ClearDelegates()
{
    foreach(var key in _values.Keys)
        if (_values[key] is INotifyCollectionChanged value && 
            _collectionChangedDelegates.TryGetValue(key, out var handler))
            value.CollectionChanged -= handler;
    _collectionChangedDelegates.Clear();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the values dictionary contains values of all types, which is why it's typed as object. However, realizing that the event is declared on the interface, rather than the ObservableCollection<> class, solves the problem. I can just test for the interface and easily cast, since there is no generic argument to worry about. Thanks!

Comment: @Michael, you are welcome. I updated the answer according to your notes.

Comment: Look how it's short and neat with fancy pattern matching feature.

Comment: Pattern matching is very awesome. Looking forward to C# 8 improvements.